# Restricting access using the X-Forwarded-For header in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up access for a directory using `.htaccess` rules. Apparently, the remote IP is always `localhost` due to the way the provider ( SourceForge.net ) has set things up.

I've noticed that the correct IP is set in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

How can I allow access only to some known hosts based on the `X-Forwarded-For` header?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-For .+ forwarded=yes
RewriteCond %{ENV:forwarded} yes
RewriteRule ... my conditions ...
```

X-Forwarded-For can contain more then one ip address if it was forwarded my multiple servers - if that is the case then you need some script to loop trough this list and processes it.